# CSS: Image transparency key

Tags: css, image, image-processing

I was wondering if this is possible in pure CSS. Suppose you have an image with white background. Is there a CSS property that removes the specified color from an image and make it transparent?

Comment: unfortunately not - would be cool though! Just spotted [PaintbrushJS](http://mezzoblue.github.com/PaintbrushJS/demo/) looks cool, maybe could extend that to do such functionality.

Comment: i dnt think their is any thing like that you have to photoshop the image...

Comment: @PhilCartmell It's a cool library; however, it's JS. I was almost sure that it is possible in JS. Though I wasn't familiar with `PaintbrushJS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Alireza, that's not possible with css I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wish there would be something like that. Next version of CSS maybe :D